# chrome/firefox- how to run a javascript command

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, gxt

I am using a gwt based ui design framework (called GXT). In the docs for this framework, it is mentioned that running "javascript:isc.showConsole()" when the app is running, will open the developer console in browser.

However when I run this in Chrome it instead does a google search for the command- in firefox it simply does not work.

How do I execute this javascript in firefox or chrome--

```
javascript:isc.showConsole()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Bookmarklets cannot be executed in the location bar/omnibox any more.

You have to bookmark the `javascript:` link before it can be executed.
A **better solution** is using the built-in Developer tools, in which code can be pasted and executed in the current page:

- Firefox:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> - See [Using the web console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_the_Web_Console).
- Chrome: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd> - See [Developer tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/overview.html).

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome, you add a tab, open bookmarks - click Other Bookmarks, right click in the bookmarks area, click add new page - and paste the URL.

In Firefox, just manage your bookmarks, click on the folder, right click in the bookmarks section and click New Bookmark.

Answer (score 0):

- You have to put the command in the URL of **the very SmartGWT
  application that you're developing**, not any blank page.
- Making it become a bookmark bar is a good idea, click that bookmark
  when you're opening the application will open the console for you.